# How to compare 2 dataframe's columns and change the existing columns occordingly in python

Tags: python, pandas, compare

I have 2 dataframes df1, df2 as shown below and the required output is also df1 as shown in df1_output.

Here, only df1's change_date columns need to be changed.

In my real use case, I have around 10 indicator columns to compare but both df1 and df2 are with around 500 rows (small df's)

```
dict_1 = {'customer_id': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
          'service_id_ind': ['n','y','n','y','n','y'],
          'service_ind_change_date':['1/1/2100','1/1/2100','1/1/2100','1/1/2100','1/1/2100','1/1/2100'], 
          'nar_id_ind':['n','n','n','n','n','n'],
         'nar_id_ind_change_date':['1/1/2100','1/1/2100','1/1/2100','1/1/2100','1/1/2100','1/1/2100']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict_1, columns = ['customer_id','service_id_ind','service_ind_change_date','nar_id_ind','nar_id_ind_change_date'])
df1
```

```
dict_2 = {'customer_id': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
          'service_id_ind': ['n','y','y','y','n','n'],
          'nar_id_ind':['n','y','y','y','y','y']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict_2, columns = ['customer_id','service_id_ind','nar_id_ind'])
df2
```

For any customer_id in df2 id_ind is changed, then in df1 the respective change_date column record for that customer_id should change to today_date.

```
dict_output = {'customer_id': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
          'service_id_ind': ['n','y','n','y','n','y'],
          'service_ind_change_date':['1/1/2100','1/1/2100','today_date','1/1/2100','1/1/2100','today_date'], 
          'nar_id_ind':['n','n','n','n','n','n'],
         'nar_id_ind_change_date':['1/1/2100','today_date','today_date','today_date','today_date','today_date']}
df1_output = pd.DataFrame(dict_output, columns = ['customer_id','service_id_ind','service_ind_change_date','nar_id_ind','nar_id_ind_change_date'])
df1_output
```

Please suggest an optimized way to code this.

Comment: Hi. Friendly advice, when you have a problem that's not easily readable, try to present a minimum reproducible example - just the minimum to get the idea through. Also, it would help to print frames table-like, using something like to_markup(). From your example it's not really clear what the update logic is.

Comment: it is unclear where your 'updated' dataframe comes from. Is there a process on how you are updating one dataframe based on the other?

Comment: Hi @34jbonz, this is a part of SCD type2 data pipeline. Df2 is the updated dataframe. I am expecting the final df1 as df1_output. Thank you

Comment: can we assume that the indices line up between the two df or no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT after request for different number of rows:

```
import datetime as dt
df1 = df1.rename(columns={'service_ind_change_date': 'service_id_ind_change_date'})  # change column name to make logic automatic
check_cols = df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns).delete(0)  # Index(['service_id_ind', 'nar_id_ind'], dtype='object')

keep_cols = df1.columns
df1 = df1.merge(df2.add_suffix('_2'), left_on=['customer_id'], right_on=['customer_id_2'], how='left')

for column in check_cols:
    df1.loc[(df1[column] != df1[f'{column}_2']) & (~df1[f'{column}_2'].isna()), f'{column}_change_date'] = dt.datetime.strftime(dt.datetime.today(), "%d/%m/%Y")

df1 = df1[keep_cols]
```

This should work if the df2 has different number of customers. It depends on customers having the same customer_id, obviously. In both cases (whichever has more customers), missing customers won't be updated.

The changes are:
keep_cols + df1.merge is to combine the two tables but to cut back to df1 in the end. I'm adding suffix because I don't like the _x _y suffixes added automatically.
Logic has added `~df1.isna()` which returns only those rows where that column is not `nan`.

---

EDIT after additional comments.

If the logic is to reset the date to today when corresponding value change, then this should be the clearest way forward.

```
import datetime as dt
df1 = df1.rename(columns={'service_ind_change_date': 'service_id_ind_change_date'})  # change column name to make logic automatic
check_cols = df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns).delete(0)  # Index(['service_id_ind', 'nar_id_ind'], dtype='object')
for column in check_cols:
    df1.loc[df1[column] != df2[column], f'{column}_change_date'] = dt.datetime.strftime(dt.datetime.today(), "%d/%m/%Y")
```

.intersection is to get the columns that show on both, and then remove the customer_id.
.loc is to select only the rows in df1 where df1 value is not the same as df2 value, and then update it with the time. Of course, you can then format the time depending on what you want, this is an example from the data.

Comment: Hi @thevoiddancer, this is not I am expecting. Whether it is 'y' or 'n', the respective change_date column should update to today's date. Thank you!

Comment: pretty sure this also does what you want in the example, but only if indices assumed same. you would just need to use datetime then to get the date. `from datetime import date` and `todays_date = date.today().strftime("%m/%d/%y")`. If the `customer_id` order changes you have to get that not the index.

Comment: Ok, so this is what I was talking about in the comment to original post. You need to explain the logic of your problem. From what I can tell now and from the comment below, is this your logic: "if value of nar_id_ind is not the same in df1 and df2 corresponding column in nar_id_ind_change_date change to today's date"? (assuming likewise for service_id_ind)

Comment: @thevoiddancer Thank u, this worked for me with small change, I added "[ ]" for the column selection in loc as shown below.                                                                      
for column in check_cols:
    df1.loc[df1[column]!=df2[column],  [f'{column}_change_date']]= dt.datetime.strftime(dt.datetime.today(), "%d/%m/%Y")

Comment: Hi @thevoiddancer, can u pls suggest a solution if the df1 and df2 are having different lengths (row_size) For instance, df2 is having 100 customers and df1 is having only 50?

Comment: Ah, this raises an interesting question. Basically, my solution above is only partially valid, because it depends on the idea that the order is identical in both frames. If that is not valid (different order, different number), we need to match an id field, such as customer_id. The answer is updated.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the problem: update `service_ind_change_date` (and other variables similarly ) in `df_1` to `today's date` if the corresponding `service_id_ind` (and other variables similarly) in `df_2` is `'y'`.

This would probably be improved if you can guarantee that they have the same indices.

I chose to use `np.where`, which uses the format `np.where(condition, response if true, response if false)`

- It gets a list of the `customer_id`s in `df2` where the `id_ind` is `'y'`: `list(df2[df2.service_id_ind == 'y'].customer_id)`
- Then checks if the `customer_id` in `df1` is in this list: `df1.customer_id.isin()`
- If true, fill in `todays_date`
- If false, keep current value `df1.service_ind_change_date`

```
from datetime import date

todays_date = date.today().strftime("%m/%d/%y")

df1['service_ind_change_date'] = np.where(df1.customer_id.isin(list(df2[df2.service_id_ind == 'y'].customer_id)), todays_date , df1.service_ind_change_date)
df1['service_id_ind '] = np.where(df1.service_ind_change_date == todays_date), 'y', 'n')

df1['nar_id_ind_change_date'] = np.where(df1.customer_id.isin(list(df2[df2.nar_id_ind== 'y'].customer_id)), todays_date , df1.nar_id_ind_change_date)
df1['nar_id_ind'] = np.where(df1.nar_id_ind_change_date== todays_date), 'y', 'n')
```

**Update with your request to change based on if the ind column changes, not if it is `y` or `n`**

If your column names are standard you can do this without writing each out.

Imagine they all take the form `{var}_id_ind_change_date` & `{var}_id_ind` similar to `nar_id_ind` & `nar_id_ind_change_date`

```
#make standard col names
df1.rename(columns = {'service_ind_change_date': 'service_id_ind_change_date'}, inplace = True)

cols_to_use = list(df1.columns.difference(df2.columns))
cols_to_use.append('customer_id')
updated_df = df2.merge(df1, on = 'customer_id')

cols_var = list(df1.columns.difference(df2.columns))
cols_ind = [i.replace('_change_date', '') for i in cols_var]

for i in np.arange(len(cols_var)):
    updated_df[f'{cols_var[i]}'] = np.where(updated_df[f'{cols_ind[i]}_x'] !=updated_df[f'{cols_ind[i]}_y'], todays_date, updated_df[f'{cols_var[i]}'])
```

If you want to keep `df1`'s `ind` like you do in the example, drop the other `ind` column and rename like so (again, columns need to be standard in form described):

```
updated_df.drop(columns = [i+'_x' for i in cols_ind], inplace = True)
updated_df.rename(columns = {i+'_y': i for i in cols_ind}, inplace = True)
```

This should match your exact output given

Comment: Hi @34jbonz, I appreciate your efforts on this and your time, Thank you! But, it is not only id_ind ='y', my problem is for a customer, any 'id_ind' variable is changed from 'y' to 'n' or 'n' to 'y'.  In simple words, any id_ind variable is changed in df2.

Comment: you can apply the same logic to other variables. Or you can merge on it and then update. I'll add an example. This goes much faster if the indices line up too. Also, if you need to repeat it for all variables easily, you would benefit from having the variable names standardized in format too.

Comment: Thanks for your help, But my problem is neither 'y' nor 'n'. If there is a change in any id_ind variable for each customer_id, the respective change_date column only should change in df1. I appreciate your patience.

Comment: I've updated further based on your description. In your example, you keep the `ind` column from `df1`, so I did the same. Also, I assumed standard variable names as I described, which makes things easier too.